# generating app keys (passwords) for google account?

Tags: security, authentication, gmail

How I can generate different app keys (passwords) to be used by different applications. I need to use gmail account for sending emails. but I dont want to put my password in file, I will use it in multiple projects to send email.

I dont want to put password in every project file, doing this when I change password I will have to change in all applications.

I'm looking for a way where I can use different keys for every applications. Please guide..

Answer (score 0):

> An App password is a 16-digit passcode that gives an app or device permission to access your Google Account.

1. Visit your [App passwords](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords) page. You may be asked to sign in to your Google Account.
2. At the bottom, click **Select app** and choose the app you’re using.
3. Click **Select device** and choose the device you’re using.
4. Select **Generate**.
5. Follow the instructions to enter the App password (the 16 character code in the yellow bar) on your device.
6. Select Done.

> Once you are finished, you won’t see that App password code again. However, you will see a list of apps and devices you’ve created App passwords for.
>
> Note: You may not be able to create an App password for less secure apps. Learn more about allowing less secure apps.

Documentation can be found here [Sign in using App password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)